# How to Solve POST and GET not Supported Warning in Java?

Tags: java, jquery, spring

In my Java application i'm sending form when hyperlink was clicked.

Now i wrote code for hyper link click event.

```
  <form:form action="demo1" modelAttribute="DEMO">
    -----
   <a href="href_form1" id="href1" class="save_details">Save</a>
    -------
  $('#href1').click(function(){
    $("#DEMO").attr("action", $('.save_details').attr("href"));
    $("#DEMO").submit();
     });
```

And my Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "demo1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String demo1(Demo demo,
        Errors errors, Model model)throws Exception {
-------//some database code
}
```

But i'm getting  Warning.

```
WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Comment: Is the `demo1` method the only method in your Controller? If not, can you add the other methods that have a `@RequestMapping` annotation?

Comment: in my class have 4 methods... but each one is different ..like @RequestMapping(value = "saveDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: Is there any method that has the `@RequestMapping` annotation with `method=RequestMethod.GET`?

Comment: yes.. one method was display all models.. @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form:form action="demo1" modelAttribute="DEMO" method="POST">
```

You have to specify that you are using POST method in your form. If you don't, GET will be used as default.